# how can i access the view page through url in a ruby on rails application using netbeans as ide?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans

I have created a new ruby on rails project using netbeans as ide. after creating an application i create a controller named hello and then view also named hello. Now when i try this in url

```
http://localhost:3000
```

, I get the homepage. But when i try this url:-

```
http://localhost:3000/hello/hello
```

the following error appears:-

We're sorry, but something went wrong.

We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.

can anyone point to me to a solution??

Answer (score 0):

Did you make a method `hello` in the hello controller? And a route to this method? Views are made for the methods, not the controller themselves. The controller name dictates the folder that those views should sit in.

Examples, really basic ones:

**config\routes.rb**

```
get 'hello/hello' => 'hello#hello'
```

**app\controllers\hello_controller.rb**

```
def hello
  @hello = 'Hello!'
end
```

**app\views\hello\hello.html.erb**

```
<%= @hello %>
```

Then visit `http://localhost:3000/hello/hello`

Comment: please can you explain it in syntax. @Matt

Comment: @PratikSharma I've added some examples but this is a very basic concept and would be much better explained in a book, check the info page of the ruby on rails tag for resources.